# Copying a discriminated union object

Tags: reflection, f#, discriminated-union

I want to make a copy of an object that is of a discriminated union type, with one or two particular fields assigned different values and any other fields copied straight across.

The tricky part is that I'm trying to write a function to do this, that will keep working unchanged even as more cases are added to the union, so I can't use `match`; instead, I'm looking for a solution that uses reflection to examine the fields of the particular case. Here's what I have so far on the reverse side, extracting values from an object regardless of its exact type:

```
let case a =
    match FSharpValue.GetUnionFields (a, typeof<Term>) with
    | info, _ ->
        info

let unpack a =
    let fields = List.ofSeq ((case a).GetFields ())
    List.collect
        (fun (field: PropertyInfo) ->
            let t = field.PropertyType
            if t = typeof<Term> then
                [field.GetValue a :?> Term]
            elif t.IsGenericType && t.GenericTypeArguments.[0] = typeof<Term> then
                field.GetValue a :?> Term list
            else
               []
        )
        fields
```

And I'm trying to write a function that starts off something like:

```
let pack a xs =
    let fields = List.ofSeq ((case a).GetFields ())
    ...
```

It occurred to me to try to use `MemberwiseClone` but that's protected, so can't be used outside subclasses. I'm probably looking for something like 'create a new object of this type, then step through the fields copying across or filling in values as appropriate' though I'm not quite sure what 'this type' would be, since `GetType` doesn't work on discriminated unions. What's the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a lot easier than it looks (ignoring the usual issues with Reflection).

You are already using `FSharpValue.GetUnionFields` to get the information about the union case and to get the values of the current union. There is also `FSharpValue.MakeUnion` which takes those information and gives you a union value:

```
type Term = 
  | Foo of int * string * bool

let a = Foo(42, "answer", false)

let case, values = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(a, typeof<Term>) 
values.[2] <- box true
FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, values) :?> Term
```